# How to check correctness of german free writings

Tags: phrase, expression, phrase-request, writing

Is there a site where my daughter could check correctness of her german writings, e.g. Aufsätze, Argumentation, Erörterungen? She could have some errors in expressions (im Ausdruck).

Comment: "Check" in which way? Syntactically? Grammatically? Stylistically? There are spell-checkers in perhaps every writing software, for everything else you better seek human advice.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something like Grammarly only in German. Apparently Grammarly itself does not cover German, but [this site](https://danielvoelk.de/en/blog/grammarly-german/) suggests some alternatives. I don't know if the suggested products/sites of free or not. As bakunin noted, a computer can only check for basic errors, spelling, grammar etc. It can't replace a human for analyzing the validity of arguments or similar tasks. I'm not sure if that's even a function of what language you're using.

Comment: Thank you bakunin and RDBury for your answers. She needs help in Linguistik e.g. which Verb goes with which Nomen.  In Grammar she is doing fine, no problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

She may like [r/WriteStreakGerman](https://www.reddit.com/r/WriteStreakGerman/). It takes about a week until someone corrects the posts. It's free.

Comment: Thank you Janka, I send a post on the link you sent me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/de) könnte sich manchmal als hilfreich erweisen.

Aus der Selbstbeschreibung:

> LanguageTool ist ein mehrsprachiges Online-Programm zur Grammatik- und Rechtschreibprüfung, das dabei hilft, Texte zu korrigieren oder umzuschreiben.

Answer (score 0):

If you write in Microsoft Word and enable German it will attempt to check both spelling and grammer. From my German native speaker perspective I would judge it as follow.

It is doing quite well on spelling unless you get into rare technical terms usually in some work specific context. So for student level writing assignments you shouldn't run into situations where it will mark correct words as wrong because it doesn't know them. However, if you write a different but correct word than what you meant of course the spell checker can't help you.

For grammar it is more tricky. It will find things like if the verb conjugation doesn't match the subject of the phrase and similar things. So it is useful, especially for a language learner. However it will also occasionally mark correct sentences as grammatically wrong. A common source seem to be using abbreviations. The grammar checker seems to have strong opinions on whether things like the UN or BMW or similar are plural or singular and these opinions don't always match with mine. So don't blindly trust what the grammar checker tells you.